# Black Screenshots In NFS Hot Pursuit (2010)

Tags: need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

When wanted level increased in NFS Hot Pursuit, a small animated clip is displayed along with information like last driven car, "Wanted level X" etc. I want a screenshot of that. Unfortunately, the PrintScreen doesn't seem to work, even after installing the 1.0.1.0 patch. All screenshots taken by PrintScreen is completely black.

Is there any other way to get that image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) to make screenshots of games.

Comment: I used Gadwin PrintScreen to take screenshot and it didn't work. Do you still think FRAPS will work? I'll try FRAPS when I get back to home.